# How to resize the table cell to fit the contents

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a GridView that I am using to display some contents:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No PDF was generated" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" SortExpression="FileName" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="File Modified Date" SortExpression="FileDate" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="25%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClick="DownloadFile" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" Text="View in Browser" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='blank';" runat="server" OnClick="ViewFile" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="35%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ToolTip="Delete File" ID="lnkDelete" OnClientClick="confirmUser()" OnClick="DeleteFile" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ImageUrl="~/delete.png" Width="50px" Height="50px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Which displays the following:

[image]

As you can see the second and the fourth column is too small. So I added the following code-behind to solve the issue:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            TableCell cell0 = e.Row.Cells[0];
            cell0.Width = new Unit("35%");

            TableCell cell1 = e.Row.Cells[1];
            cell1.Width = new Unit("20%");

            TableCell cell2 = e.Row.Cells[2];
            cell2.Width = new Unit("15%");

            TableCell cell3 = e.Row.Cells[3];
            cell3.Width = new Unit("15%");

            TableCell cell4 = e.Row.Cells[4];
            cell4.Width = new Unit("15%");
        }
    }
```

But the result is still the same. How can I modify/add to my code so that the first column  is smaller and the second and the fourth column is stretched out to ensure the contents are shown correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

I changed my first `<asp:BoundField />` to this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" SortExpression="FileName" ItemStyle-CssClass="checkIt"></asp:BoundField>
```

And added the following `CSS`:

```
.checkIt {
     width: 30%;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On every column, you have to specify its own width. To do this click on the smart tag > Edit Columns > Choose the column then in the property list go to HeaderStyle > Width and set it as 100.

Comment: I am sorry, rephrase that question, I am having a hard time understanding it. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't resizing the header row (which is what I am doing, presumably) makes the subsequent rows the same size?

Comment: Yes. It does in fact.

Comment: It's not working. I update my code with the new settings but it's the same still...